CiviCRM on WordPress SMARTY issue Tag 'crmAPI' disabled by security setting
I am using CiviCRM v5.75.0 on WordPress v6.6.1
When I go to generate a PDF Thank You letter using a saved smarty template that used to work, I get the following error message:
Message was not parsed due to invalid smarty syntax : Tag 'crmAPI' is not allowed in secure mode.

Going to system status, I see a message about Smarty Update that tells me to put the following into civicrm.settings.php :
define('CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH', '/path/to/civi/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/autoload.php');
When I try to generate the PDF again, I get similar but different error message:
Message was not parsed due to invalid smarty syntax : Syntax error in template "eval:{crmScope extensionKey=""}<!-- ** TEMPLA..." on line 55 "{crmAPI var='resultFinancialType' entity='FinancialType' action='get' id=$financial_type_id}" tag 'crmAPI' disabled by security setting

So I am not sure what I need to do to fix this.
Thanks

See https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2024-03-smarty-security-policy
You can either use the mentioned hook or you might be able to replace the crmapi call with a token, since there are more tokens nowadays.

Intersesting behavior... When I first added the hook/function and tried again, it succesfully generated the PDF except the PDF was completely blank. Then when I try do it again (making sure the hook/function is still active), I start getting the same error about crmAPI being disabled by security settings.
